# How to retrive predefined list of items in swiftUI from firestore?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have 2 types of collections:

1. Classes
2. Students

Each class can have multiple students and vice versa.

What is my best way to store and fetch all students in a class (or the other way around)?

---

Here's a snapshot of a class:
[image]

---

What I did so far is to have a field of type array for each item that should contain the list of IDs of the students/classes. But using whereField to retrieve the students is no good since it's limited to 10 only. Also, for some reason, even when I fetch the 9 students for a class it won't reflect changes in real-time when I change the data in Firestore so I suspect there's a better way to do this.

I also tried to fetch all students and loop on this list against the classes list and append it to a new array - but this works very poorly and again, I suspect it's useless overhead.

Is there a good practice for my need?

Comment: "fetch all students in a class" Can you share a screenshot of your Firestore document and show how you storing student's class in their doc?

Comment: Sure, I've added to the original post

Comment: Please provide some code. What did you try. What errors did you get? [Minimal example Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: But that's the thing, my code is somewhat working but I'm not looking to fix what I did but to learn about a good approach on how to fetch documents by a list of IDs from Firestore since the straightforward approach (whereField) is not good because of the 10 docs limit.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone will ever seek a solution for this - here's the approach that I took and worked.

My first (complex and not so good) approach was:

1. Fetch students array from a class
2. Fetch students from students collection base on the students' array
   (*this won’t work if you have more than 10 items in the array)
3. If you have more than 10 items, fetch all students, loop on them against the students' array, and filter out whichever student is not in the array.

The approach that worked:

1. For every student in the class, add the classID
2. Fetch all students and use whereField to filter by classID

   .whereField("students", arrayContains: classID)

Here's a diagram of everything:
[image]